# Android MenuItem Get Method for showAsAction

Tags: android, menuitem

I am looking for the complimentary method to **mentuItem.setShowAsAction()**, i.e. **menuItem.getShowAsAction()** as there doesn't seem to be one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html

As I need to record the current state before setting them to  MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER, so when the orientation of the device changes back to landscape I can return the menu items to their old state.

I need to do this as Honeycomb doesn't provide a new row to show tabs like in ICS. So in honeycomb there is not enough space given to the tabs.

Is there another universal get properties method in Java or Android to find the setting in the XML for the attribute showAsAction in menuitem.

thanks

Comment: Did you find anything? I am looking for the same method.

Comment: No could not find anything. And it's not honeycomb (as I had been testing it on a Honeycomb device at that time) but it actually affected certain screen configurations like extra-large and in portrait mode. But in Honeycomb it wasn't able to remember the menu items state and rebuild it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method, from what was said in the other answer:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private int getShowAsActionFlag(MenuItem item) {
    MenuItemImpl itemImpl = ((MenuItemImpl) item);
    if (itemImpl.requiresActionButton()) return MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS;
    else if (itemImpl.requestsActionButton()) return MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM;
    else if (itemImpl.showsTextAsAction()) return MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT;
    else return MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the below class has this method **isActionButton()**

> **android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl**

Please note that **MenuItem** is an interface and not a class from which the supposed menuitem object instance was created.

If you are using the android.support.v7 compatibility package, simply cast the menuitem object to **MenuItemImpl**.

It is done like this:

```
((MenuItemImpl)item).isActionButton()
```

Comment: Furthermore the mentioned class offers the methods `requestsActionButton()`, `requiresActionButton()` and `showsTextAsAction()` which help you detect wether the flags `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM`, `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` or `SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT` are set, and you don't have to fiddle around with the bitmask!

Comment: @Taig Do you mind explaining a bit how to get with this methods the value of flag(s) used in setShowAsAction()?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension if anyone prefers

```
val MenuItem.showAsActionFlag: Int
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    get() {
        this as MenuItemImpl
        return when {
            requiresActionButton() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            requestsActionButton() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
            showsTextAsAction() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT
            else -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER
        }
    }
```

You can use it like

```
if (item.showAsActionFlag == SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
```